# Horrific errors and WSOD

Tags: wsod

I was installing the panels module when all of a sudden my site went to white screen of death with a whole bunch of error messages. (Check this out here: http://graphbyte.co/fuck.png ).

Right before I tried to install panels I had abandoned the process of creating a custom page. I realized I hadn't enabled the panels module, which I needed for this custom page, so I jumped into the modules page and attempted to install it.

I tried deactivating the panel module directly from the database but that had no impact on the situation.

What can I do??? Please helllllp!!

Thanks,

G

Comment: This seems unrelated to Panels or Drupal per se.  Have a look here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1644572/2332745

Answer (score 0):

OK I found out that that error in particular is due to not having a large enough allowed packet size in your mysql configuration. Here is a bit more info on that:

http://is.gd/pV7c2M

If you're running LAMP, here is how you can create a configuration file and increase your max packet size limit:

http://is.gd/mI3B82

Answer (score 0):

For reference, here's a link to the Drupal.org documentation to check WSOD problems: https://drupal.org/node/158043